# Using another Controller/view inside the One controller/view by ajax and CakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I m having a three controllers in my app:

1. Forms
2. attributes
3. Users

In my /forms/designpage I'm posting the data as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./attributes/untitledfieldname",
    data: "sequence_no = " + counter + " & type = " + type,                                     
    success: function(msg){
    }//success
});//ajax
```

Since I am having my untitledfieldname action inside Users Controller, in the URl i gave as ./attributes/untitledfieldname. But this doesn't works.

### Edit:

I have changed the URL .Actually my went like forms/attributes/untitledfieldname
where forms is m base ctrller and attributes is my another ctrller. Now I put the Direct URL. Now it works.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, feel free to post an answer to this question for others' reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
// ...
url: "<?php echo $html->url('/controller/action'); ?>",
// ...
```

Also, consider using $.post rather than $.ajax